# Show a table row when a field value is less than a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the age value is less than 15, I want to show the below hidden table row.

```html
<td>Age</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none">
      <td> Guardian</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="guardian" id="guardian"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Can you share what have you achieved so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show code and effort

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery it would be something like

```
$("#age").on("input",function() { // or "keyup" or "blur"
  $(this).closest("tr").next().toggle(this.value<15);
});
```

You need to not have the input for guaridan hidden, though

Comment: I guess blur would suit better in this case.

Comment: @Rajesh: No it wont. Blur will be only triggered when input loses focus..

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Just consider the case where your age is 31. Now when you type 3, handler will check if `value<15` and will show the row. Now you type 1(value = 31). Now since `value<15` is false, it will hide again. In my understanding, a user will move out only when he has finished and we should process our logic that time only

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/z1q21far/2/)

I slightly modify your html:

```
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='trGuardian' style="display:none">
    <td> Guardian</td>
    <td>
      <input name="guardian" id="guardian">
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

And JQuery :

```
$("#age").blur(function() {
  if (parseInt($(this).val()) < 15)
    $('#trGuardian').show();
  else
    $('#trGuardian').hide();
});
```